# Python altering column based on other values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['A','A','A','B','C','C'], 'colB':['X','nm','X','nm','nm','nm']})

x
Out[254]: 
  colA colB
0    A    X
1    A   nm
2    A    X
3    B   nm
4    C   nm
5    C   nm
```

I want to replace values on column B in the following:

For each unique value of column A, if colB contains value X, then replace all colB values with "X", i.e. replace all values 'nm' with X for each group of values of column A.

If a group in column A (e.g. values 'C' in this example) do not contain a value of 'X' in column B then just leave 'nm' alone.

The result should be:

```
Out[254]: 
  colA colB
0    A    X
1    A    X
2    A    X
3    B   nm
4    C   nm
5    C   nm
```

I have attempted to do this using group by's and counting the number of "X" values which appear in each unique value in column A but I feel it's very convoluted. Hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with groupby.transform:

```
x.groupby('colA')['colB'].transform(lambda col: 'X' if 'X' in col.values else 'nm')
Out: 
0     X
1     X
2     X
3    nm
4    nm
5    nm
Name: colB, dtype: object
```

Assigning it back:

```
x['colB'] = x.groupby('colA')['colB'].transform(lambda col: 'X' if 'X' in col.values else 'nm')

x
Out: 
  colA colB
0    A    X
1    A    X
2    A    X
3    B   nm
4    C   nm
5    C   nm
```

Comment: could you please give some more information on how transform is working here? There is such little documentation and you seem to came to the conclusion so quickly. I have searched for 2 hours now and do not think I fully understand what it's doing.

Comment: @user33484 There are two main operations on grouped DataFrames: Aggregation and transformation. Aggregation generates a single value for each group. For example if you group by gender, you can calculate the mean weight for males and females. At the end you have two data points: mean weight of males and mean weight of females. Now assume that for each individual you want to calculate the difference between their weights and the mean weight. This still uses an aggregated value but also *transform*s each individual data point in the Series.

Comment: So if you want to end up with a single value for each group, you can use groupby.agg but if you want to change each observation based on some characteristics regarding their group, you should use groupby.transform. In this example, we are following the same two steps: 1) Does the group contain 'X' (aggregation - returns a single value either True or False) 2) If True, change all values to X (transformation)